# Spark Streaming - Kafka - java.nio.BufferUnderflowException

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, cloudera, kafka-consumer-api, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm running into below error while trying to consume message from Kafka through Spark streaming (Kafka direct API). This used to work OK when using Spark standalone cluster manager. We just switched to using Cloudera 5.7 using Yarn to manage Spark cluster and started to see the below error.

Few details:
- Spark 1.6.0
- Using Kafka direct stream API
- Kafka broker version (0.8.2.1)
- Kafka version in the classpath of Yarn executors (0.9)
- Kafka brokers not managed by Cloudera

The only difference I see between using standalone cluster manager and yarn is the Kafka version being used on the consumer end. (0.8.2.1 vs 0.9)

Trying to figure if version mismatch is really an issue ? If indeed the case, what would be the fix for this other than upgrading Kafka brokers to 0.9 as well. (eventually yes but not for now)

`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 200.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 200.0 (TID 203,..): java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:151)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(ByteBuffer.java:715)
    at kafka.api.ApiUtils$.readShortString(ApiUtils.scala:40)
    at kafka.api.TopicData$.readFrom(FetchResponse.scala:96)
    at kafka.api.FetchResponse$$anonfun$4.apply(FetchResponse.scala:170)
    at kafka.api.FetchResponse$$anonfun$4.apply(FetchResponse.scala:169)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at kafka.api.FetchResponse$.readFrom(FetchResponse.scala:169)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$toLocalIterator$1$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$anonfun$$collectPartition$1$1.apply(RDD.scala:942)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$toLocalIterator$1$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$anonfun$$collectPartition$1$1.apply(RDD.scala:942)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: This is due to incompatibility with Kafka version. Spark 1.6.x only supports Kafka 0.8.x. This issue occurs if you try Spark 1.6.x with Kafka 2.x for e.g. having said that with Spark 2.x, this should not be an issue since Spark Kafka direct streaming has been upgraded to work with Kafka 0.9 and 0.10